# External hard drive connected to lan

Tags: local-area-network, hard-drive

Is there a way to connect an external driver to my lan network (direct connection, without having any PC opened) and then access it from any device from lan? Like a network drive?

If its not possible, can you please recommend a sollution? I am asking this so all my development files will be easily accessed by all my lan devices.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of single-drive NAS that will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Some hard-drive cases have a LAN plug and a minimal operating system allowing file sharing. So you'll need a case or an adapter to share your files on the network. (I'm assuming you already have the disk. If you don't, you can just buy a little NAS like the WD ones.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want look into what is called [NAS - Network-attached storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage). Quote:

> A NAS unit is a computer connected to a network that provides only
>   file-based data storage services to other devices on the network.

Ready-made products come in all shapes and sizes, depending on what exactly your needs are (redundancy, computational and I/O power, etc.). Some manufacturers might be [Synology](http://www.synology.com/), [Qnap](http://www.qnap.com/) and [Buffalo](http://www.buffalo-technology.com/en/).

As others have pointed out, a NAS with a single bay might already be enough for your purposes. You would install your hard drive, hook it up to the network and you'd pretty much be good to go. The setup and user interfaces of these products tend to be very user friendly.

In the end, most of them run (sometimes more, sometimes less heavily) modified versions of Linux under the hood. It can be great fun to tinker with them, too.

Hope that helped!